# CakePHP Application: some pages with SSL, some without

Tags: cakephp, ssl, https

I have an application written with the CakePHP framework and it is currently located in httpdocs. I want a few pages to be redirected to https://

Basically this shouldn't be a problem to detect whether the user is already on https://... or not. My issue is a different one: In my opinion I would need to make a copy of the whole project and store it in httpsdocs, right? This sounds so silly but how should it work without duplicating the code? I think I miss something but I don't get it ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never had to copy the code for ssl. You should specify in the vhost for the site what the path is.

On apache there is a vhost for each, ssl and non ssl. Both can have the same webroot path.

Answer (score 1):

If your webhoster requires you to put the https part of your website in httpsdocs, then you will need to put something there. But not the whole project: maybe only the /web part (the part that is actually served up by the webhoster).

Something like

```
/cake/app/  --> your app code
/httpsdoc/..  --> index.php and possibly css stuff, images etc
/httpsdocs/.. --> copy of index.php and the rest as well
```

Of course, you could also use some internal redirect in .htaccess

One suggestion: now that google indexes https urls, you could also choose to make the whole site available through https.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The https-part is only for internal use so I created the SSL certificate on my own just for encryption. Making the whole site available through https would bother my users with security warnings. I think I will try to use internal redirects on the server.